# How to run a function after wp() in the wp-blog-header.php file?

Tags: hooks, actions, wp-blog-header.php

I want to run a function after the `wp();` line in the file `wp-blog-header.php`, what is the proper `hook` to use here?

```php
<?php
/**
 * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

    $wp_did_header = true;

    // Load the WordPress library.
    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

    // Set up the WordPress query.
    wp();

    /********************************************
       I WANT TO RUN THE FUNCTION AT THIS POINT 
     ********************************************/

    // Load the theme template.
    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );

}
```

#### Why do I need the hook

We are migrating to a new website and we have to care about the old URLs, so what I did:

1. Added the following `rewrite` rule to our `NGINX` config file:

`rewrite \D+(\/\d+\/\D+)$ /index.php?redirect=$1 break;`

This rule will add an extra parameter `redirect` to the URL (old URL) with a value that I will be using to get the new final URL.

2. Then I will run the following code to get this value from the incoming URL and get the final URL by querying a 2-columns table that maps each value `redirect_from` with a final URL `redirect_to`:

```php
/**
 * 1. Check if the URL has a parameter [redirect]
 * 2. If NO, proceed to the next step
 * 3. If YES, then get that parameter value and look into [redirects] table
 * 4. If you found a row that has that value, then get the [redirect_to] value
 * 5. Redirect to that URL [redirect_to]
 */

if (isset($_GET['redirect'])) {
    // Get the parameter value from the URL
    $redirect_from = $_GET['redirect'];
    // Add the table prefix to the table name
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'redirects';
    // The SQL query
    $query = "
        SELECT redirect_to
        FROM $table_name
        WHERE redirect_from = '$redirect_from';
    ";
    // Run the SQL query and get the results
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);

    // If there was a result then do the redirection and exit
    if (wp_redirect($result[0]->redirect_to)) {exit;}
}
```

**Note:**
No way to get the new URLs from old URLs, here is an example of the old and new URLs:

Redirect from:

`http://www.example.com/category/sub-category/post-id/slug`

to:

`https://www.example.com/category/sub-category/yyyy/mm/dd/slug`

Comment: There’s lots of hooks that run at various places after that. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Thank you @JacobPeattie , I've already updated the question, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate hook for handling redirects would be `template_redirect`:

```
function wpse_331804_redirects() {
    /**
     * 1. Check if the URL has a parameter [redirect]
     * 2. If NO, proceed to the next step
     * 3. If YES, then get that parameter value and look into [redirects] table
     * 4. If you found a row that has that value, then get the [redirect_to] value
     * 5. Redirect to that URL [redirect_to]
     */

    if (isset($_GET['redirect'])) {
        // Get the parameter value from the URL
        $redirect_from = $_GET['redirect'];
        // Add the table prefix to the table name
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'redirects';
        // The SQL query
        $query = "
            SELECT redirect_to
            FROM $table_name
            WHERE redirect_from = '$redirect_from';
        ";
        // Run the SQL query and get the results
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);

        // If there was a result then do the redirection and exit
        if (wp_redirect($result[0]->redirect_to)) {exit;}
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_331804_redirects' );
```

Comment: Thank you @JacobPeattie, I think this will work, I will try it and then flag it as the accepted answer if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could put your redirect function into a must-use plugin and hook the function to `muplugins_loaded`. $wpdb should be available then and I think it would minimize the amount of code loaded in the case a redirect is needed.

You can also have a look at the action reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference to find other hooks.

Comment: Thank you @AnttiKoskinen, actually, I don't want to go with plugins because we have about 120K redirections that could cause a performance issue if I went with a plugin.

Comment: My thinking was that you could potentially make the redirect faster by putting the redirect function into a must-use plugin (a single file in wp-content/mu-plugins) and doing the redirect check on `muplugins_loaded`. If you look at the Action Reference, you'll see that `muplugins_loaded` is the first action on the list whereas `template_redirect` is the 27th (if I counted correctly).

Comment: If `$_GET['redirect']` isset and there's a match from the custom DB table, the redirect would kick-in and it would happen way before for example `init`, which fires before `template_redirect` and is commonly used by theme and plugins to initialize stuff. I think the DB query you're doing inside your redirect function takes the same time regardless which action it is hooked to. But by using an action that fires earlier you'd minimize the amount of included and processed PHP.

Comment: It worths a try, thanks a lot @AnttiKoskinen.